# How to reset Apple ID password without email access

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I received my wife's old iPhone and created an Apple account in my name. When I go to settings her name pops up. I hit that and it wants her password, however she doesn't remember.  She no longer has the email she signed up under so I can't have an email sent to the account.  Is there a way to change the name and account?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Apple's iForgot](http://iforgot.apple.com) page and enter your Apple ID. From there, choose the Security Questions option and answer the questions. If you are correct, you should be able to reset the password. If not, you may have to contact Apple Support or go into an Apple Store.